# Return list of empty array Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a json with empty keys and I would like to display all empty keys in my div below.

thanks everbody

**js data**

```
  fly: []
  flight: [
   {
    id: "1", 
    name: "apollo",
    rocket:"ariane"
   }
  ]
 }
```

**ts**

```
   @Input flight: any[];
```

**html**

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of flight">
       <span>{{item.flight.name}}</span>
    </div>
    
    <div *ngIf="flight.length == 0">
      // here i don't know the next step
    </div>
```

Comment: Please be aware that the JSON is not valid. All properties names should be quoted with double-quotes

Comment: You couls start with hello, but also with more details like what is the expected output because here I don't understand what you mean by empty array, is it normal if it's empty or not ? because you also use an input so it seem a bit confusing

Comment: What do you mean by displaying empty keys? What should it look like? Have you tried the Json-Pipe from Angular? https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Comment: the json is an example I wrote at home to visualize the thing, when a value is empty I want to display it in the div below

Comment: @herve, can you share the desired result that you want to display?

Comment: in my json the fly key is empty and I want to display it and make a loop for the other fields that are empty and that I want to display

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are not clearly defining your data and using the name "flight" in multiple places, with various meanings. Your data is an object, not an array. and then flight is an array contained within your data. You probably want something more like this:

```
data = {
  fly: [],
  flight: [
  {
   id: "1", 
   name: "apollo",
   rocket:"ariane"
   }
  ]
 }
```

then use this:

```
@Input data: any;
```

You should be accessing `let item of data.flight` not `let item of flight`

and finally `*ngIf="data.flight.length == 0"`